# Author's derivation of time-independent form of Maxwell's equations

Tags: complex-analysis, vector-analysis, physics, electromagnetism

*Laser Electronics, 3rd edition*, by Joseph T. Verdeyen, gives the following:

> To describe an electromagnetic wave, we need two field-intensity vectors, $\mathbf{e}$ and $\mathbf{h}$, which are related to each other by
>
> $$\nabla \times \mathbf{h} = \mathbf{j} + \epsilon_0 \dfrac{\partial{\mathbf{e}}}{\partial{t}} + \dfrac{\partial{\mathbf{p}}}{\partial{t}},$$
>
> $$...$$
>
> where $\mathbf{p}$ is the polarisation current induced by the electric field.
>
> ...
>
> Most of the time we will be talking about sinusoidal variations of the field and use the phasor representation
>
> $$\mathbf{j}(\mathbf{r}, t) = \mathcal{R}e[\mathbf{J}(\mathbf{r})e^{j\omega t}],$$
>
> $$\mathbf{e}(\mathbf{r}, t) = \mathcal{R}e[\mathbf{E}(\mathbf{r})e^{j\omega t}],$$
>
> $$\mathbf{p}(\mathbf{r}, t) = \mathcal{R}e[\mathbf{P}(\mathbf{r})e^{j\omega t}],$$
>
> $$...$$
>
> where $\mathcal{R}e$ is the real part, $\mathbf{r} = x \mathbf{a}_x + y \mathbf{a}_y + z \mathbf{a}_z$, $\mathbf{a}_i$ is the unit vector in the $i$th direction, and the capital letters $\mathbf{E}$ and $\mathbf{H}$ are complex vector quantities depending on space coordinates but not on time.
>
> By substitution, we obtain the time-independent form of Maxwell's equations:
>
> $$\nabla \times \mathbf{H} = \mathbf{J} + j \omega \epsilon_0 \mathbf{E} + j \omega \mathbf{P} = \mathbf{J} + j \omega \mathbf{D},$$
>
> $$...$$
>
> where $\mathbf{D} = \epsilon_0 \mathbf{E} + \mathbf{P}$

It seems to me that the author thinks that $\mathcal{R}e[\mathbf{J}(\mathbf{r})e^{j \omega t}] = \mathbf{J}$, when it seems to me that it should be $\mathcal{R}e[\mathbf{J}(\mathbf{r})e^{j \omega t}] = \mathcal{R}e[\mathbf{J}(\cos(\omega t) + j \sin(\omega t))] = \mathbf{J} \cos(\omega t)$?

I would greatly appreciate it if people could please take the time to review this.

Comment: I think $\mathbf{J}$ is complex, no?

Comment: @user10354138 I don't think so; at least, I don't see any indication of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the original equation is
$$\operatorname{rot}(h) = j + \varepsilon_0 \partial_t e + \partial_tp$$
Substituting back everything, we get that
$$\operatorname{rot}\left(\Re\left(H\exp(i \omega t)\right)\right) = \Re\left(J\exp(i \omega t)\right) + \varepsilon_0 \partial_t \Re\left(E\exp(i \omega t)\right) + \partial_t\Re\left(P\exp(i \omega t)\right)$$
$$\Re\left(\operatorname{rot}\left(H\exp(i \omega t)\right)\right) = \Re\left(J\exp(i \omega t)\right) + \Re\left(\varepsilon_0 \partial_t E\exp(i \omega t)\right) + \Re\left(\partial_tP\exp(i \omega t)\right)$$
$$\Re\left(\operatorname{rot}\left(H\exp(i \omega t)\right)\right) = \Re\left(J\exp(i \omega t) + \varepsilon_0 \partial_t E\exp(i \omega t)+\partial_tP\exp(i \omega t)\right)$$
$$\Re\left(\operatorname{rot}\left(H\right)\exp(i \omega t)\right) = \Re\left(J\exp(i \omega t) + \varepsilon_0 E\partial_t \exp(i \omega t)+P\partial_t\exp(i \omega t)\right)$$
$$\Re\left(\operatorname{rot}\left(H\right)\exp(i \omega t)\right) = \Re\left(J\exp(i \omega t) + \varepsilon_0 Ei \omega \exp(i \omega t)+Pi \omega\exp(i \omega t)\right)$$
$$0 = \Re\left(J\exp(i \omega t) + \varepsilon_0 Ei \omega \exp(i \omega t)+Pi \omega\exp(i \omega t)-\operatorname{rot}\left(H\right)\exp(i \omega t)\right)$$
Now let
$$f=J + \varepsilon_0 Ei \omega +Pi \omega -\operatorname{rot}\left(H\right)$$
Then we have that
$$0=\Re(f \exp(i \omega t))$$
$$0=\Re(f)\Re(\exp(i \omega t))-\Im(f)\Im(\exp(i \omega t))$$
And it should be true $\forall t$, so if we let $t=0$, we get that
$$0=\Re(f)$$
And if we let $\omega t = \frac{\pi}{2}$, we get that
$$0=\Im(f)$$
Which means that
$$\Re(f)+i\Im(f)=f=0$$

Comment: Hmm, what do you mean "dropped the $\mathcal{Re}$-s"? I don't see how it is valid to just arbitrarily drop them?

Comment: @ThePointer I'm on my computer now, so I'm gonna complete my answer.

Comment: @ThePointer I think my argument should be fine in this case. In physics, you can see a lot of time that they are looking for the solution in complex functions, and taking the real part of it at the end.

Comment: I've cleared up my misunderstanding. Thanks!